# Assigning text to GUI text fields in random order for a multi choice math quiz

Tags: java

I have written a simple programme using random number generator that generates two random number, then it adds them together to calculate the correct answer which will be one of the options given to the user. Also, I have managed to generate two false answers, again using random number generator. The correct answer and two false answers are displayed in the textview boxes.

As it stands, the correct answer always appears in the same box. I am trying to figure out how to shuffle the answers so they appear in the textview boxes randomly.

I would very much appreciate some guidance. Also, as you can probably tell, I am just starting out with Java. Thank you in advance.

public void generate(View view) {

```
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    int number1 = rand1.nextInt(10);
    int number2 = rand2.nextInt(10);

    int ans_correct = number1+number2;
    int ans_wrong1 = ans_correct+1;
    int ans_wrong2 = ans_correct+2;

    TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.num1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    TextView ansa = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.a);
    TextView ansb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);
    TextView ansc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.c);

    text1.setText("" + number1);
    text2.setText("" + number2);
    ansa.setText("" + ans_correct);
    ansb.setText("" + ans_wrong1);
    ansc.setText("" + ans_wrong2);


}
```

Comment: Are you storing you textboxes in an array, a list, or some other way?

Comment: What happens when you search for a method named "shuffle" in the Java API doc? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index-files/index-19.html

Comment: Do you have some code that we can see, showing what you've already tried ?

Comment: My text boxes are stand alone. I can post the code I am using once I get home in few hours.

Comment: It would be worth holding off asking questions like this until you can post some code - see the quide on  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  That way you are likely to get the best help that is most appropriate to your situation.  Also - it would be worth choosing a title that more precisely describes the actual *programming* problem you are encountering.

Comment: P.S. The fact that you are talking about "textview" makes me think you might be developing an Android app using [`android.widget.TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) is that right? If so - it would be a good idea to tag your post `Android` and also capitalise the `TextView` correctly as it may affect the answer you get (in detail at least, if not in principle).

Comment: I am trying to develop a simple app that adds two numbers for my six year old. all question should have three answers, two wrong and a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this does not guarantee there will be wrong answers, but you should get the idea.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
Integer randomIntA = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
Integer randomIntB = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
Integer answer = randomIntA + randomIntB;
ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
answers.add(answer); 
answers.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(200)); 
answers.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(200)); 
Collections.shuffle(answers);
jTextFieldA.setText(answers.get(0));
jTextFieldB.setText(answers.get(1));  
jTextFieldC.setText(answers.get(2));
```

Comment: The code is very similar to what I wrote except the array bit. Looks promising. I will try and let you know how I got on.

Comment: As a beginner you might find useful to know that in order to use ArrayList you need to **import java.util.ArrayList;** at top of your code file.

Comment: I am using android studio. I will make sure I include this in imports. Thank you.

Comment: Related question. Assume I had three numbers in a array. Let's say 1,2,3 and had three textviews. How could I put a number in textview from an array and make sure it was not same as any other box?

Comment: Try not to ask extra questions in comments - they usually won't attract much attention - you can always ask a follow up question (as I said above - usually worth waiting until you are at a machine with the code so that you can post it).  To use an array - it's still easiest to wrap it in an `ArrayList` for example by using [`Arrays.asList(myArray);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) - you'll need to import `java.util.Arrays`.  Then shuffle as per this answer. If you have a fundamental reason to use array directly - ask a new question with code.

Comment: I have now added my code to the question. Hopefully, this will make more clear what I am trying to do.